# Static map api returns different location than maps.google.com for address

Tags: google-maps

I'm looking for this address with the static maps api: 105 W. County Road Y
Oshkosh, WI 54901.

The static Maps URL that I use to return the map image is: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&center=105+W.+County+Road+Y,Oshkosh,WI,54901&markers=color:blue%7C105+W.+County+Road+Y,Oshkosh,WI,54901&size=250x250&zoom=15  (I removed the api key)

This returns a marker that is different than what maps.google.com returns: https://maps.google.com/maps?q=105%20W.%20County%20Road%20Y%2C%20Oshkosh%2C%20WI%2054901

What's weird is that if you change the address in the static maps URL to 105 E. County Road Y, Oshkosh WI 54901 this returns the marker that should be returned from the 105 W. County Road Y.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a google maps issue
(I'm guessing that it's me, but I just don't know how to fix it..)

Thanks

Comment: for me both map-types show the markers at the same location. However, the **W.** doesn't make any sense here as it seems, you may replace the **W.** with a **X.** and get the marker at the same location.

Comment: I don't get the marker at the same location. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2003708/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-27%20at%209.50.58%20PM.png  the image on the left is maps.google.com, the one on the right is what comes back from static maps.

Comment: This question is not about the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)